# Notify when a system UIAlertView dismisses

Tags: ios

I'm trying to use the new Photos Framework but I can't seem to find a way to be notified when the "allow access to photos" alertview finishes. Any Thoughts?

I tried doing it through a notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIWindowDidResignKeyNotification object:self queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    //figure out the result of the request
    // This never gets called
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the provided API which gives you exactly what you want.

```
+[PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:(void (^)(PHAuthorizationStatus status))handler]
```

> This method always returns immediately. If the user has previously
>   granted or denied photo library access permission, it executes the
>   handler block when called; otherwise, it displays an alert and
>   executes the block only after the user has responded to the alert.

Comment: Awesome. Which class has this method?

Comment: Oops, sorry. `PHPhotoLibrary`.

Comment: Also take a look at `registerChangeObserver:`, which will notify you if the user changes the permission during runtime.